# cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2' (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I was trying to import the following libraries in jupyter notebook at once:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from dash import no_update
```

However, I got the following error:

```
cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2' (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py)
```

Please what is missing?
Thank you.

Comment: There's probably an issue with your versions. Do you have Flask installed in your environment?

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.